# Debugging a "Warning (bytecomp): reference to free variable" message

Tags: package, debugging, warning

I just upgraded to a new bleeding edge version of Emacs in OS X:

```
brew install emacs --HEAD --use-git-head --with-cocoa 
--with-gnutls --with-rsvg --with-imagemagick
```

I understand that this version is not stable and that I shouldn't expect it to wok without any problems. Still, my experience so far has been relatively positive installing from `HEAD` directly.

For some reason, after today's update, I now run into this warning when I start Emacs. I am hoping to debug this problem using `setq debug-on-message` as suggested in many threads without luck.

I tried adding  `(setq debug-on-message "Warning (bytecomp)")`
or `(setq debug-on-message "Warning \(bytecomp\)")` at the beginning of my `.emacs` file and starting Emacs with `emacs --debug-init`, but I don't see any trace either in the `Compile-Log` or the `Messages` log.

I have also tried re-compiling all packages from scratch, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24735377/1732769), i.e. doing `M-: (byte-recompile-directory package-user-dir nil 'force)`, but the problem persists.

How can I effectively debug this type of warning?

Comment: Not an answer, but if you don't want random error messages, random errors, or even random crashes. I would not suggest you use the bleeding edge development version.

Comment: You haven't actually stated how you get that warning. I assume it happens at startup?

Comment: **Show the complete warning message** here. Presumably it mentions a particular variable or a particular function where the variable seems to be free. If the latter, try using `(debug-on-entry 'THE-FUNCTION)` in your init file, and step through the debugger to see what goes on. Or `grep` for the variable or function name to see what library uses it and how. You should not need to recompile anything. IOW, it's standard needle-in-haystack debugging, if you really care to see what's going on.

Comment: `bughunter` also fails to reproduce these warnings, meaning that it cannot be used to bisect the configuration.